# Accessing other computers synced through Google Drive from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sync, google-drive

I have a Ubuntu desktop and a Macbook Air. I use the Google Drive mac app (Backup and Sync) to sync everything on my laptop. I can access it from my phone, I can access it from a browser etc.

However, when I set up Google Drive on Ubuntu 18 (using GNOME online accounts), the only files I saw were the files on my Drive, not any of the files synced through my laptop.

How can I access my files from my Macbook? If not google drive, something else?

[Note I checked a bunch of other questions, they all have to do with syncing Drive for Ubuntu files, this is not quite the same]

[image: screenshot]